# Python with MAMP not working

Tags: python, mamp

I'm in the process of switching from PHP over to Python.

The web project I'm on is very very small (probably just two to three script files) so I would prefer to avoid any framework and just work with Python.

I'm running MAMP (not the Pro version) on OS X Yosemite.

My python test file works fine when executed in the terminal.
But when I open it in the browser, it just shows the text connect of the file, not the output.

`PyTest.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# enable debugging

import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print
print 'Hello, World!'
```

I'm really new to Python. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: So you know that MAMP is for Apache and **P**HP?

Comment: @u_mulder yes but the information on their website suggests that python scripts should work as well. Am I totally getting things wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I did not completely understand the way Python and Webservers interact and why it wouldn't work with MAMP out of the box.

I'm now using a lightweight web framework (bottle) which has a small development server built in.

The website later will be deployed using NGINX and uWSGI.